# How to process html in twig file

Tags: theming, 8

I've a plain text field, where I've added few text in wrapped in  tag. I've tried to get the processed html text in the twig by using

```
   {{ content.field_front_page_description|field_value }}
    {% set text = content.field_front_page_description|field_value %}
      {% set build = {
      '#type':   'processed_text',
      '#text':    text|render,
      '#format': 'full_html',
      } %}
      {{ kint(build) }}
      {{ build }}
```

But it is returning an array with not processed text. How do I do that

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by `processed html`. Is this a twig file of a node, page or ??? In other words, what is the name of your twig file?

Comment: Are you trying to build a render array and render it? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @NoSssweat It is a twig file for a node. I have a plain text field, and I've few tags in it. I'm trying to get the processed text form that.

Comment: @Jaypan I'm trying to process the HTML of the field. i'm not trying to build a render array. I just want to know how to apply checkmarkup in twig.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Code** -

```
{% set build = {
      '#type':   'processed_text',
      '#text':    content.field_front_page_description.value,
      '#format': 'full_html',
} %}
      {{ kint(build) }}
      {{ build }}
```

**Or,**

```
{% set build = {
      '#type':   'processed_text',
      '#text':    node.field_front_page_description.value,
      '#format': 'full_html',
} %}
      {{ kint(build) }}
      {{ build }}
```

Comment: It didn't work, see my above code what I've done

Comment: what is your field name? and what is field_value in your code?

Comment: To get the field value only I've used a module called twig_field_value. So by giving content.field_front_page_description|field_value, it will only give the value. not the label of the field

Comment: try my edited code only and see if it reflects changes

Comment: It is not working